# Fast computing of statistics in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, performance, statistics, innodb, myisam

Well, I have a big MySQL table with good indexes and some data and I need to make a statistics report for these data. It means I have a lot of things in query like this

```
select 
  count(*) n,
  sum(if(column1>0,1,0)) n1,
  sum(if(<simple expression>,1,0)) n2,
  sum(if(<another simple expression>,1,0)) n3,
  ....
from table1
left join table 2 ...

group by <simple expression>
```

The issue is this query is very slow. Converting this whole table from InnoDB to MyISAM reduces this query time from 30 seconds to 8 seconds which is good, but MyISAM has other limits which prevent to using this table by multiple users at the same time (TABLE LOCK actually locks whole application).
I understand that the reason for the need to load the entire table into memory. Given that the table has several gigabytes in size, it is almost impossible, which is why we have such slowing.
I am looking for good solution for this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In MySQL booleans have integer representation, so you can sum them up directly.

Comment: Can you try each select-value in a seperate query? It may be possible that only one of them isn't optimized correctly or is slowing down the others or something. Mysql may be needing different indexes for each of the values and be loosing speed because of that. Take a look at each of them seperately first to see which one is fast and which one is slow.

Comment: @PM77-1 means this: you can use `SUM(column1>0)` in place of `SUM(IF(column1>0,1,0))`

Comment: Thirty seconds is tolerably good performance for a whole-table-summarizing report query. You're not going to get it down to 100 milliseconds. You may, or may not, be able to use an index to help accelerate the query. But there's no way we can offer advice on that without knowing the exact query and the structure of the tables.

Comment: @PM77-1 It not helps. I've removed if(..,1,0) and query time was not changed.

Comment: @OllieJones Ok, look here is explain for my query and result. This query runs for 6 seconds. http://epsiloncool.ru/i/E20140928-005545-001.png

Comment: Try creating a compound index on manualcheck: `(ischecked, isgood, id)`.  This may help with the index intersect on the first row of your explain. Read about compound indexes.

Comment: @OllieJones I've tried to add column 'id' to compound index, but it was not help. Here is my current indexes http://epsiloncool.ru/i/E20140928-013012-001.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Statistic can be fully counted 1 time in a day (or hourly), and we can use TRIGGERs to catch table modifications and modify current statistic, stored in special "cache" table.
Thus we will have ready stat report in that table. Almost 0 time to getting statistic report!